# Как по клику на <i> добавить значение в div?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая HTML структура:

```
<div class="pol"></div>
<div class="change">
    <i>1</i>
    <i>2</i>
    <i>3</i>
    <i>4</i>
    <i>5</i>
    <i>6</i>
    <i>7</i>
    <i>8</i>
    <i>9</i>
</div>
```

Таких структур у меня 80 штук. Необходимо чтобы по клику на число оно добавлялось в `.pol`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: копировалась или переносилась? Каждую цифру можно использовать только раз или сколько угодно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно добавить обработчик события `click` каждому `<i>`, в котором в качестве текста в `.pol` устанавливать соответствующее число:

```js
var pol = document.querySelector(".pol");
document.querySelectorAll(".change i").forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    pol.textContent = element.textContent;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="pol"></div>
<div class="change">
  <i>1</i>
  <i>2</i>
  <i>3</i>
  <i>4</i>
  <i>5</i>
  <i>6</i>
  <i>7</i>
  <i>8</i>
  <i>9</i>
</div>
```

---

Если нужно не заменять текст в `.pol`, а добавлять число в конец текста, то достаточно использовать `pol.textContent +=` вместо `pol.textContent =`.

---

Так как в вопросе отсутствует метка jQuery, то и в решении jQuery не используется.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я вижу, что у меня добавляется когда через breakpoint смотрю, но по факту, на странице число не отображается, я думаю мне нужно через перебор сделать, потому что у меня в массиве находиться 81 класс pole. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать через for для 81 класса pole. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Извините, я неправильно выразился. Для одного вы мне помогли, большое спасибо! А если у меня есть таких 9 штук(pole и change), которые находятся в ещё одном диве. Как правильно сделать, что бы я мог в каждый pole добавлять любые цифры из change? Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил, спасибо!

Comment: @Aleksander что-то [типа такого](https://jsfiddle.net/zudq1xLk/)?

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно

Comment: @Aleksander для каждого блока по отдельности тогда [можно сделать так](https://jsfiddle.net/zudq1xLk/1/).

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector(".change").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'I') {
    document.querySelector(".pol").textContent += e.target.textContent
  }
})
```

```css
.pol:empty:before { content: "\A0" }
```

```html
<div class="pol"></div>

<div class="change">
  <i>1</i>
  <i>2</i>
  <i>3</i>
  <i>4</i>
  <i>5</i>
  <i>6</i>
  <i>7</i>
  <i>8</i>
  <i>9</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Будет тоже полезным...*

```js
;(function(){
 var polElems = document.getElementsByClassName('pol');
 var changeElems = document.querySelectorAll('.change > i');
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(changeElems, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(){
   var self = this;
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(polElems, function(pol){
    var newItem = self.cloneNode(true);
    // Может пригодится
    newItem.addEventListener('click', function(){
     this.remove();
    });
    pol.appendChild(newItem);
   });
  });
 }); 
})();
```

```html
<div class="pol"></div>
<div class="change">
<i>1</i>
<i>2</i>
<i>3</i>
<i>4</i>
<i>5</i>
<i>6</i>
<i>7</i>
<i>8</i>
<i>9</i>
</div>
<!-- для примера  --> 
<div class="pol"></div>
<div class="pol"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно чтобы просто добавлялось как тест, тогда вот самый простой вариант как по мне:

```js
$('.change').on('click', 'i', function() {
 $('.pol').append($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pol"></div>
<div class="change">
<i>1</i>
<i>2</i>
<i>3</i>
<i>4</i>
<i>5</i>
<i>6</i>
<i>7</i>
<i>8</i>
<i>9</i>
</div>
```

Comment: всюду лепят этот jQuery..тошнит уже от него) без обид